# When I have the ID of a user in Facebook, how can I have the URL of its profile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In our website, when users use Facebook to connect, we take their user ids from Facebook.
We would like to have the URL to the profile for each user id. How can we do that?

I couldn't find this question here (but on the other way url -> id).

Answer (score 2):

You can´t get access to the real profile of users, since the username is not in the response of `/me` anymore and the ID is just an "App Scoped ID". This is to protect the privacy of the user, you should never need access to his profile anyway.

If you just want the picture of the user, you can use the picture endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[app-scoped-id]/picture
```

Comment: We would like to let announcers who put ads on our website to be contacted by others via Facebook (just a link to their profil). We already have profil picture. Thanks for you answer luschn !

Comment: that´s one reason why it´s not possible anymore. if you want to contact someone, you have to request his email in the authorization or ask for contact details after authorization. people don´t want to get contacted without their explicit authorization (not facebook authorization).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but I try to rephrase:

You want to be able to create the link to the profile, and you're having the app-scoped ids.

If that's the case, you can build the link to the profiles in the following manner:

```
https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/{app_scoped_id}/
```

where `{app_scoped_id}` is to be replaced with the actual id. This can also be derived from

```
/me?fields=link
```

with the individual access token.